# Error parsing list of products in dart flutter using http

Tags: flutter, http, dart

I have an api from where i want to parse some data , i have a plugin that convert data into dart model class , but whenever i try to get the response , it keeps showing an error if anyone could help , will be appreciated

- This is the api link

```
 https://fakestoreapi.com/products/category/electronics
```

- This is the model class ( generated using plugin for dart )

```
class ProductsModel {
    String category;
    String description;
    int id;
    String image;
    double price;
    String title;

    ProductsModel({this.category, this.description, this.id, this.image, this.price, this.title});

    factory ProductsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return ProductsModel(
            category: json['category'], 
            description: json['description'], 
            id: json['id'], 
            image: json['image'], 
            price: json['price'], 
            title: json['title'], 
        );
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['category'] = this.category;
        data['description'] = this.description;
        data['id'] = this.id;
        data['image'] = this.image;
        data['price'] = this.price;
        data['title'] = this.title;
        return data;
    }
}
```

- This is how i'm parsing data

```
void main(){
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: FirstScreenApp(),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  ));
}

class FirstScreenApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstScreenAppState createState() => _FirstScreenAppState();
}

class _FirstScreenAppState extends State<FirstScreenApp> {

  Future<ProductsModel> _getElectronics() async {
    var url = "https://fakestoreapi.com/products/category/electronics";
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      // success
      var decodedResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      return ProductsModel.fromJson(decodedResponse);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       body: FutureBuilder<ProductsModel>(
         future: _getElectronics(),
         builder: (context,data){
           if(data.hasError){
             return Center(
               child: Text("Error " + data.error.toString()),
             );
           }
           if(data.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
             return ListView.builder(
               itemCount: 4 ,
               itemBuilder: (context,index){
                 return Container(
                   margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                   child: Card(
                     elevation: 10,
                     child: Padding(
                       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                       child: Row(
                         children: [
                           Image.network(data.data.image),
                           SizedBox(height: 10,),
                           Column(
                             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                             crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                             children: [
                               Text("League : " + data.data.title),
                               Text("Sport : " + data.data.category),
                               Text("DP : " + data.data.price.toString())
                             ],
                           ),
                         ],
                       )
                     ),
                   ),
                 );
               },
             );
           }
           return Center(
             child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
           );
         },
       ),
    );
  }
}

 * This is the error generated
```

type 'List is not a subtype of type <Map<String,dynamic>>'

Comment: API response has more than 1 product. It's a list.

Comment: and when i return a list , it shows an error as well , the plugin shoul ve generated a class that holds list of products , but two plugins did the same thing im confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch the list of JSON in the following way.

```
 Future<List<ProductsModel>> _getElectronics() async {
    var url = "https://fakestoreapi.com/products/category/electronics";
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // success
      List decodedResponse = json.decode(response.body);

   
      return decodedResponse
          .map((data) => ProductsModel.fromJson(data))
          .toList();
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load data');
    }
  }
```

you can just copy-paste my code and thanks me.

```
 import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class FirstScreenApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstScreenAppState createState() => _FirstScreenAppState();
}

class _FirstScreenAppState extends State<FirstScreenApp> {
  Future<List<ProductsModel>>? loadedData;
  Future<List<ProductsModel>> _getElectronics() async {
    var url = "https://fakestoreapi.com/products/category/electronics";
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // success
      List decodedResponse = json.decode(response.body);

      // var d=decodedResponse.map((data) => ProductsModel.fromJson(data)).toList();
      print(decodedResponse[1]);
      return decodedResponse
          .map((data) => ProductsModel.fromJson(data))
          .toList();
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load data');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    loadedData = _getElectronics();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<ProductsModel>>(

        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text("Error " + snapshot.error.toString()),
            );
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 10,
                    child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Image.network(snapshot.data![index].image!),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                    "League : " + snapshot.data![index].title!),
                                Text("Sport : " +
                                    snapshot.data![index].category!),
                                Text("DP :  ${snapshot.data![index].price!} ")
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        )),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          }
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
        future: loadedData,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is your model class

```
class ProductsModel {
  final category;
  final description;
  final id;
  final image;
  final price;
  final title;

  ProductsModel(
      {this.category,
      this.description,
      this.id,
      this.image,
      this.price,
      this.title});

  factory ProductsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ProductsModel(
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
      price: json['price'],
      description: json['description'],
      category: json['category'],
      image: json['image'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['category'] = this.category;
    data['description'] = this.description;
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['image'] = this.image;
    data['price'] = this.price;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: it worked thank you , anyway examplation why do we need to map the data and then turn it to list , thank you !

Comment: ProductsModel is a map and we need multiple ProductsModels

Comment: we actually need List<ProductsModel> which means List of Map

Answer (score 0):

Model class

```
`class ProductsModel {
  final String? category;
  final String? description;
  final int? id;
  final String? image;
  final price;
  final String? title;
  final Rating? rating;

  ProductsModel(
      {this.category,
        this.description,
        this.id,
        this.image,
        this.price,
        this.title,
        this.rating
      });

  factory ProductsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ProductsModel(
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
      price: json['price'],
      description: json['description'],
      category: json['category'],
      image: json['image'],
      rating: json['rating']!= null ? Rating.fromJson(json['rating']) : null,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['category'] = category;
    data['description'] = description;
    data['id'] = id;
    data['image'] = image;
    data['price'] = price;
    data['title'] = title;
    if (rating != null) {
      data['rating'] = rating?.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}



class Rating {
  final rate;
  final int? count;
  Rating({
    this.rate,
    this.count});

  factory Rating.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Rating(
      rate: json['rate'],
      count: json['count'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['rate'] = rate;
    data['count'] = count;
    return data;
  }
}
`
```

How to call api

```
    import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'model/product_model.dart';

class FetchProductList {
  var data = [];
  List<ProductsModel> results = [];
  String urlList = 'https://fakestoreapi.com/products';

  Future<List<ProductsModel>> productList({String? query}) async {
    var url = Uri.parse(urlList);
    try {
      var response = await http.get(url);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        data = json.decode(response.body);
        results = data.map((e) => ProductsModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
        if (query!= null){
          results = results.where((element) => element.title!.toLowerCase().contains((query.toLowerCase()))).toList();
        }
      } else {
        print("fetch error");
      }
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print('error: $e');
    }
    return results;
  }
}
```

Home screen

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_signin/model/product_model.dart';
import 'package:firebase_signin/reusable_widgets/produact_card.dart';
import 'package:firebase_signin/screens/search.dart';
import 'package:firebase_signin/screens/signin_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../api_service.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final FetchProductList _productList = FetchProductList();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey.shade300,
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showSearch(context: context, delegate: SearchUser());
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.search)),
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut().then((value) {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const SignInScreen()));
                });
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.logout_outlined))
        ],
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        title: const Text(
          "Product List",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: FutureBuilder<List<ProductsModel>>(
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: Text("Something went wrong"),
                  );
                }
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ProductCard(
                        title: snapshot.data![index].title!,
                        description: snapshot.data![index].description!,
                        price: snapshot.data![index].price!,
                        thumbnailUrl: snapshot.data![index].image!,
                        rating: snapshot.data![index].rating?.rate,
                      );
                    },
                  );
                }
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              },
              future: _productList.productList(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

reuable widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProductCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final price;
  final String thumbnailUrl;
  final rating;
  const ProductCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    this.price,
    required this.thumbnailUrl,
    this.rating
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 22, vertical: 10),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 250,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.black,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                  offset: const Offset(
                    0.0,
                    10.0,
                  ),
                  blurRadius: 10.0,
                  spreadRadius: -6.0,
                ),
              ],
              image: DecorationImage(
                colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                  Colors.black.withOpacity(0.35),
                  BlendMode.multiply,
                ),
                image: NetworkImage(thumbnailUrl),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        const Icon(
                          Icons.star,
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                          size: 18,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 7),
                        Text(rating.toString(),style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const Text(
                '\$',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19, color: Colors.white),
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                maxLines: 1,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              _reusableText(context, price.toString()),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 5),
          _reusableText(context, title),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _reusableText(BuildContext context, String string) {
    return Text(
      string,
      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 19, color: Colors.white),
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      maxLines: 1,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    );
  }
}
```

output will be look like that[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbOYw.jpg)