# setState doesn't update the ListView data

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, dart-async

I want to load data on `ListView` from API on only button click event not in `initState()`. I getting data from server but not updated on ListView.

I searched for this but not get any proper solution, I'm new in flutter.

here's my code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<dynamic> ListData = [];

Future _getData() async {

      String apiUrl = "http://myURL";
      final params = {"id": "1", "keyword": "xyz"};

      var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(apiUrl),
        body: params,
      );

      var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);

      List<dynamic> DATA = [];
      DATA = jsonData['data'];

      setState(() {
        ListData = DATA;
      });

      print('DATA COUNT: ${ListData.length}');

      return ListData;
    }
}
```

I'm getting here "DATA COUNT" properly, check below `button` & `ListView` code.

```
    SizedBox(
     height: 45,
     width: 60,
     child: ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.orangeAccent,
            ),
     onPressed: () async {
     await _getData();
     print('button pressed ${ListData.length}');
     },
     child: Text(
     '${ListData.length}',
     style: TextStyle(
     fontSize: 18.0,
     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
     ),
    ),
   ),
  ),
Expanded(
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: ListData.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return ListTile(
        title: Text('${ListData[index]}'),
      );
    },
  ),
),
```

I'm getting data here "button pressed" also properly, but not updated on `button text` and `ListView builder`, what is wrong in this my code thanks in advance.

Comment: is your data in a server is a list of the map?

Comment: You can see this answer it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67844897/error-parsing-list-of-products-in-dart-flutter-using-http/67846290#67846290

Comment: And another thing is,  don't use the POST method while incase of fetching data from a server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your ListData from build method. The reason is when setState is called each time method will be rebuild and hence it will make your ListData empty each time.

```
List<dynamic> ListData = [];

`@override

Widget build(BuildContext context) {



Future _getData() async {

  String apiUrl = "http://myURL";
  final params = {"id": "1", "keyword": "xyz"};

  var response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(apiUrl),
    body: params,
  );

  var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);

  List<dynamic> DATA = [];
  DATA = jsonData['data'];

  setState(() {
    ListData = DATA;
  });

  print('DATA COUNT: ${ListData.length}');

  return ListData;
}
```

}`

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning ListData = [] in you build Methode. When your build Methode is called by setState() ListData is assigned to [] again.

Try to assign ListData = [] abough your build methode